pine script version 5 - How to use plot lines values in stead of macd values for conditional color
screenshot how it now plotted
1below simple script draws an upper and lower band, based on MACD values
the problem occurs when filling in area in between. The change of color does not really match
the change of direction of the band, because the change of color is based on MACD values while
the band reacts a little slower.
//@version=5
indicator("MACD bands", overlay=false)
fastmacd_usr = input.int(100, title='Fast', minval=1, inline="b", group="MACD settings")
slowmacd_usr = input.int(200, title='Slow', minval=1, inline="b", group="MACD settings")
signal_usr = input.int(100, title='Signal', minval=1, inline="b", group="MACD settings")

fast_ma = ta.ema(close, fastmacd_usr)
slow_ma = ta.ema(close, slowmacd_usr)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = ta.ema(macd, signal_usr)
delta = macd - signal

plot(macd, title = "macd", color=color.red, linewidth=1, display=display.none)
plot(0, title = "zero line", style=plot.style_line, color=color.gray)
biasUp = plot(ta.highest(macd, 25), style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.red)
biasDown = plot(ta.lowest(macd, 25), style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.green)

trendUp = ta.highest(macd,25) > ta.highest(macd[1], 25)
trendDown = ta.lowest(macd,25) > ta.lowest(macd[1], 25)
noTrend = ta.highest(macd, 25) == ta.highest(macd[1], 25) or ta.lowest(macd, 25) > ta.lowest(macd[1], 25)

trendColor = trendUp ? color.new(color.green, 70) : color.new(color.red, 70)

fill(biasUp, biasDown, trendColor, "Trend", fillgaps = false)


I am unable to use the upper and lower band as input for the conditional color change in the fill function
The area should turn green when biasUp is higher and should red when biasDown is lower
Who can help ??
(i just started with pine script few days ago)

biasUp will always be higher than biasDown. You are using highest() and lowest() to set their values with the same source and length.

Gm Vitruvius, thanks for helping me. Added a screenshot how it looks now. The fill colour changes while the bands do not (yet). Pls provide some details how to adjust my code. Thanks again.

Can you show when you want the colors to change?

Hi, green fill as soon as upper band goes up and red fill as soon as lower band falls (that is the reason i choose for plot.style_stepline to visually mark trend change for myself as a confirmation besides the color change). Thanks !!!
